# QMap datatype in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am using Qt 5.9.4 opensource. Is there any QML type similar to QMap?
Currently I am using a C++, which is holding a QMap. Using Q_INVOKABLE methods, retrieving information from QMap in the QML code.

**Question:**

Will this create any performance issue, as i m retrieving data from C++ in QML? Is there any way to have map datatype in QML itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use **JavaScript** objects - they are close to maps/dictionaries, for example:

```
var myMap = {x: "Test", y: "Test 2"};
myMap["z"] = "Test 3"
console.log(JSON.stringify(myMap))
```

outputs `{"x":"Test","y":"Test 2","z":"Test 3"}`.

*Note: `JSON.stringify` is used just to make output more readable, it is not a part of my solution.*

Answer (score 0):

If you make your QMap a QProperty you will be able to access it directly from the qml. As far as any performance concerns this documentation covers that nicely in regards to QProperties. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-performance.html